How to handle windows path in posix environment in C++?
std::filesystem::path::format doesn't have windows format :-/
How to create a windows path on posix system?
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::filesystem::path win_path{"c:\\toto.txt",
        std::filesystem::path::format::auto_format}; // I want to specify windows format
    std::cout << win_path
        << (win_path.is_absolute() ? +" is absolute\n" : +" is relative\n");
    // Detected as relative on posix system
}

Demo

What OS are you running this on?  "c:\\toto.txt" is a relative path on POSIX or POSIX-like systems like Linux.

I know it would be a valid relative path on Posix system, but I know that it is for a windows path. I'm testing some windows config file from posix systems (ubuntu/msys2 currently). Just path manipulation (/, relative), no "system" action (open/create_directory, ...).

<< " " << std::filesystem::absolute(win_path) << "\n" looks like it is being interpreted in a POSIX environment.

@Eljay: std::filesystem::absolute(win_path) results in "/app/c:\\toto.txt" Demo...

You'll have to do it the same way you'd specify a DEC VMS path on a non-DEC VMS system:  you'll have to write your own.
